# OOP - Python - printing instance variable too when I call static method alone

Tags: python-3.x, class, object, oop, static-methods

Here in this code I am just calling out my static method, but it prints my instance variable too. Could you please explain the reason for that, and how to avoid them being printed?

Like below:

**I am a static Method**

**None**

```
class Player:
    
     def __init__(self, name = None):
        self.name = name # creating instance variables
         
     @staticmethod
     def demo():
         print("I am a static Method")
         
p1 = Player()

print(p1.demo())
```

Comment: It isn't printing your instance variable, ```print``` returns ```None``` it is showing what the print function prints and what it returns. Ie if you change it to ```name = 2``` in ```__init__``` it will still show ```I am a static Method
None```

Comment: Then how can we avoid return statement being shown on output

Comment: You could just change it to ```return "I am a static Method"```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Python docs says](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print):

> Print objects to the text stream file, separated by sep and followed
> by end. sep, end, file, and flush, if present, must be given as
> keyword arguments.

So you can `return` your message in method and then just `print` it:

```
class Player:
    
     def __init__(self, name = None):
        self.name = name # creating instance variables
         
     @staticmethod
     def demo():
         return "I am a static Method"
         
p1 = Player()

print(p1.demo())
```